# How to add screen to custom bottom navigation in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm new to react native and trying to design a custom Bottom navigation bar as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LsLgHeX500) ([Source code](https://github.com/wcandillon/can-it-be-done-in-react-native/tree/master/bonuses/tabbar))

The tab bar design is successfully created, but I am confused about how to change screens on button click.
Basically, I cannot understand how to connect the React Native Navigation Component to this custom bottom tab bar.

I'm looking forward to using [React navigation custom navbar support](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaroptions)... but not sure how to implement the same.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Navigation Docs are really helpful. Check out my solution [here](https://snack.expo.io/@royk/custom-bottom-navigation-bar).

The solution is to just add a reference of the custom tab bar design in the usual navigator definition and pass the state, descriptors, navigation props from the Navigator to the custom design as shown below.

**/components/BottomBar/index.js**: Define the navigation model and use Tabbar as custom design.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { View } from "react-native";
import  TabBar  from "./Tabbar";
import Screen1 from "../../screens/Screen1";
import Screen2 from "../../screens/Screen2";


export const BottomMenu = () => {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  return (
    
    <View style={{ flex: 1, position: "relative",  justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
    
      <Tab.Navigator
        tabBar={(props) => <TabBar {...props} />}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="screen1" component={Screen1} />
        <Tab.Screen name="screen2" component={Screen2} />
        <Tab.Screen name="screen3" component={Screen1} />
        <Tab.Screen name="screen4" component={Screen2} />
      </Tab.Navigator>     
  
    </View>
   
  );
};
```

**/components/BottomBar/TabBar.js**: Pass the navigator props to the static tab bar along with the custom icon details.

```
const { state, descriptors, navigation } = this.props
 :
<StaticTabbar {...{ tabs, value, state, descriptors, navigation }} />
```

**/components/BottomBar/StaticTabbar.js**: Using the props display the items in the tab bar

```
    const { tabs, value } = this.props;
    const { state, descriptors, navigation } = this.props
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          state.routes.map((route, index) => {
            const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
            const tabOption = tabs[index];
              :               
            const key = index;
            return (
              <React.Fragment {...{ key }}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => onPress(index)}>
                  <Animated.View style={[styles.tab, { opacity }]}>
                    <Icon name={tabOption.name} color="white" size={28} />
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 11, color: 'white' }}>{tabOption.text}</Text>
                  </Animated.View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                <Animated.View
                  style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: -7,
                    left: tabWidth * index,
                    width: tabWidth,
                    height: 64,   // Tab bar height
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    opacity: opacity1,
                    transform: [{ translateY }],
                  }}
                >
                  <View style={styles.activeIcon}>
                    <Icon name={tabOption.name} color="#004c40" size={25} />
                  </View>
                </Animated.View>
              </React.Fragment>
            )
          })}
      </View>
      );
```

Comment: Hey can u check this question its something related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65792242/how-to-make-custom-tabbar-react-navigation

Comment: @OliverD... yes the question is related... You have to follow the same solution mentioned here...

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried to do that, but you probably can do that by using default stack navigator: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating
So, what is the idea. You create 5 different screens and on each of them make a copy of this tabbar. Then you write a conditional statement for every possible case with navigation.navigate prop. I think this is the only way, but I don't know how that will affect the performance of the app

Comment: I'm looking for something like https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaroptions ... but not sure how to implement the same

Comment: @R.K Here is showing how to add an onPress event to the tabbar: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar  so mb try this one. To add custom icons you need to create a font with them. So use this website: https://fontello.com/  or this one:  https://icomoon.io/app/#/select . You need to rebuild or your tabbar to implement what you want to do. Read more React Navigation docs, cause they give a lot of useful information